# ошибка в Android Studio 3.6 при Build Project

Tags: android-studio, kotlin

Используем kotlin, все работало нормально пока что-то не обновилось
помогите разобраться что это может быть?

8:35    Unsupported Modules Detected: Compilation is not supported for following modules: android. Unfortunately you can't have non-Gradle Java modules and Android-Gradle modules in one project.

Comment: Пробовали `File -> Invalidate Caches / Restart -> Invalidate Caches & Restart.`?

Comment: попробовал, ничего не поменялось

Comment: Что за версия 3.6? Только сегодня (через два месяца после задания вопроса) вышла версия 3.5.